# Eclipse: New shortcut doesn't work ("Select next change" in a compare window after rename)

Tags: eclipse

I searched for an answer at this site and generally in the Internet, but didn't find a solution. I'd like to use shortcut keys for almost all my actions in Eclipse, but it doesn't work in some case. When I rename a class, a preview of all changes to be performed is shown, with a list of the changes on top, original source below on the left side and refactored source below on the right side. The command buttons "Select Next Change" and "Select Previous Change" (two arrows - down and up) are visible at the top right corner of this preview window and I can use them in order to navigate to the next or previous change. I can do it with a mouse. A default shortcut doesn't exist for this action, so I assigned a new shortcut to it, which is not used for any other command (no conflicts), using Preferences > General > Keys. However, the shortcut doesn't work. I tried all solutions which I found on the web, i.e.:

- I checked if the assigned shortcut is not used for any other command
- I assigned a different shortcut to the command
- I restarted Eclipse

I also have tried a solution which worked in case of another shortcut to the following command from the context menu: "Compare With" > "Latest from Repository":

1. Window / Customize Perspective...
2. Select tab "Command Groups Availability"
3. Scroll down to "SVN" and enable it.

However, I tried enabling different command groups in the case of the shortcut for the "Select Next Change" command and enabled some command groups and it didn't help. 
Anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution which makes it possible to use only keyboard in this case, but it works as a shortcut to the "Next/Previous Change" command (navigates only inside of one file) instead of the "Select Next/Previous Change" (navigates through all files in the list of changes). I performed the following steps:

- Go to Preferences > General > Keys

  - Find the "Select Next Change" command
  - Check the binding ("Ctrl+." in my case)
  - Change the value of "When" to "In dialogs and windows" (from "In windows")
- Do the same as described above for the "Select Previous Change" command (with other binding - "Ctrl+,")

Now I can navigate using keyboard shortcuts inside of one changed file, but have to use arrow keys (left, down etc.) to navigate to the next changed file. I didn't find a way to define a shortcut for the global "Select Next Change" command which navigates through all changes in all changed files.

Comment: If you found partial solution then edit your question. DO NOT POST the  explanation as answer.

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK I think it's often fine to post partial solutions, that can be later edited into a full solution, or deleted in light of better answers. This is a partial answer, not an "explanation" as you claim.